# How do I fetch all categories under a category group using the Element API?

Tags: craft3, plugin-elementapi, elementquery

I am not too familiar with PHP and am just learning the Element API.
How do I turn this craft query into an element api query?

`craft.categories.group("brands").level(1).all(),`

In categories this is what it looks like

```
Brands
    -Luxury
        -Gucci
        -Chanel
        -Louis Vuitton
    -Streetwear
        -Supreme
        -Bape
        -Off White
OtherCategory
    - ...
SomeOtherCategory
    - ... 
    - ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE** 
Figured it out based on another answer from [ElementAPI handling CategoryModel and returning a heirachical object](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/15220/elementapi-handling-categorymodel-and-returning-a-heirachical-object)

I wrote the query like this:

```
'api/categories/<entryCat:[\w-]+>' => function ($entryCat) { 
  return array_merge(apiConfig(), [
      'elementType' => Category::class, 'criteria' => ['group' => $entryCat, 'level' => 1, 'with' => ['children.children.children']],
      'transformer' => function (Category $category) {
        $data = ['title' => $category->title];
        $children = $category->getChildren();
        if ($children) {
            $data['children'] = [];
            foreach ($children as $child) {
              $data['children'][] = ['title' => $child->title];
            }
        }
        return $data;
      },
  ]);
},
```

where `apiConfig()` is just common settings such as `pg` and `paginate`